# Базовая настройка почты Exim

Tags: email, exim

Есть VPS. На нем установлен Exim со стандартной конфигурацией. Прописана MX запись `mail.source.ru`. MTA работает и отправляет сообщения через:

```
mail -s "Example subject" -r from@source.ru to@target.ru
```

Но при подключении по telnet:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

и наборе:

```
> HELO source.ru
> mail from: from@source.ru
> rcpt to: to@target.ru
< 451 temporary local problem
```

сообщение не отправляется и в логах есть ошибка:

```
temporarily rejected RCPT to@target.ru: Could not complete sender verify
```

Возможно, причина в неправильном использовании `telnet`. Как тогда правильно его использовать/настроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось следующим. Прописываем в `/etc/exim/exim.conf`:

```
domainlist relay_to_domains = source.ru
```

После сообщения с `info@source.ru` начинают отправляться, а с какого-нибудь `abc@source.ru` получается ошибка:

```
550-Verification failed for <abc@source.ru>
550-Unknown user 
550-Sender verify failed
```

Добавляем в файл `/etc/aliases`:

```
abc: postmaster
```

Таким образом, начинает работать переадресация для псевдоаккаунтов. Вопрос в том, зачем это нужно при отправке сообщений остается открытым.